# Post Request is not reaching to the server when request body is large but no issue with small request body

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am using `Angular 5` and `Spring boot`, when I am trying to send a Post request with heavy body size, I am getting below error but there is no issue with small body size -

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-.......' from origin
> 'https://....' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Error description points to CORS problem. It is explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i . I doubt it is related to the size of request body.

Comment: You can try installing 'CORS' extension on chrome, and toggle CORS to check if problem persists.